# Solidworks CSWA part modelling question

Tags: solidworks

I am having difficulty with a CSWA question that asks to find the mass of the following part. Here is a link to my attempt: https://drive.google.com/file/d/162No5ugwQ-9cRkdcp-78Ohq08T8UngBd/view?usp=sharing

[image]

[image]

Can anyone identify what I did wrong? I selected answer choice A which is closest to the mass of my model but that is incorrect. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I haven't even looked at the dimensions of your part yet, but you've assigned the wrong material! AISI 1020 is not the same as AISI 1020 Steel, Cold Rolled. The Question specifies the density as 7900 kg/m^3, but you were using a material with 7870kg/m^3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. So, there's actually a few problems.

1. Per my comment, you selected the wrong material, which has the wrong density.
2. I quickly modelled the part myself so I could do a part compare to see how your geometry differed. The "Red bit" is your part sticking out of the correct geometry. You can see that the position of the top isn't in the correct place.

[image]

3. I then opened your sketch to see how you had got this wrong - and was met with a fully 'blue' sketch. Your sketches should *always* be fully defiled (black). You simply had not dimensioned the position of the upper circle in the horizontal direction at all - the orange dimension shown on the image is one *I added* to show that it's not 30mm per the drawing.

[image]

4. When I added this missing dimension, and set it to 30mm, the model fell over/broke, - your whole model has been built in an unstable way using odd tools (boss extrude instead of fillet on the R100s, for example?

5. I've attached an example model here: http://www.filedropper.com/cswaexample I'm happy to help explain some best practice and tutor you through this model to give some transferrable skills for future CSWA tests, but, StackExchange isn't the best forum for this. Try the SOLIDWORKS Discord?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have a question about the cut extrude in your CSWA example file. I deleted it and tried to recreate it and to select the appropriate sketch entities I create a corner rectangle (here is a link to my attempt: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZTrV.png) but I am unable to select the appropriate regions to extrude. Can you tell me how you selected the appropriate contours to extrude?

Comment: You don't need the square around the outside (the "corner rectangle"), you just need to check the "flip side to cut" box in the cut extrude dialog to effectively get an intersect feature instead of a cut.

Comment: That sketch still looks under constrained, though - I can see blue vertices through the highlight!

Comment: It's best to avoid having to select sketch regions, as these can be broken easily if you need to edit the sketch. Better usually to trim the sketch entities so SW can use the whole sketch rather than just one region.